# change string in a big list with another string

Tags: python, regex, string, list, replace

i have some list as t_pre_eks_tfberita

[image]

i want to replace the string in row with "Label" string that contain "BUKAN HOAX (1)" to "BUKAN HOAX" and change a string that contain "HOAX (1)" as "HOAX". 
but i found error when i use this code.

```
for i in range (len(t_pre_eks_tfberita)):
if(t_pre_eks_tfberita[i][0]=="Label"):
    j=1
    while j in range (len(t_pre_eks_tfberita[i])):
        cek = re.search("BUKAN",t_pre_eks_tfberita[i][j])

        if(cek):
            t_pre_eks_tfberita[i][j] = "BUKANHOAX"
        else:
            t_pre_eks_tfberita[i][j] = "HOAX"
        j+=1

dfr_eks_tfberita = pd.DataFrame(list(map(list, zip(*t_pre_eks_tfberita))))
new_header = dfr_eks_tfberita.iloc[0] #grab the first row for the header
dfr_eks_tfberita = dfr_eks_tfberita[1:] #take the data less the header row
dfr_eks_tfberita.columns = new_header

for i in range(len(new_header)):
    if new_header[i] != 'Label' and new_header[i] != 'Isi_Dokumen':
        dfr_eks_tfberita[new_header[i]] = dfr_eks_tfberita[new_header[i]].astype('int')

dfr_eks_tfberita
```

when i run it, i found error like this.

[image]

any solution for this problem?

Comment: `cek = re.search("BUKAN", str(t_pre_eks_tfberita[i][j]))`? Actually, you may just use `in` with a string, no need to use `re` if you want to check for a fixed substring presence in another string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i tried cek = re.search("BUKAN", str(t_pre_eks_tfberita[i][j])) but it takes very long time to run it is okay? i want to change any "BUKAN HOAX (1)...(500)" for all the number to "BUKAN HOAX", and all "HOAX (1)....(500)" to "HOAX" in other words, i want to remove all number from that string

Comment: I suggest that you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

using re is in overkill here.
you need to traverse the df values, and just check if "BUKAN HOAX (1)" or "HOAX (1)".

```
if "HOAX (1)" in t_pre_eks_tfberita[i][j]:
    dosomething()
```

but you can actually do it inside the DF using pandas own function like iterrows().

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, try `pandas.Series.str.replace` with `strip`:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['HOAX', 'HOAX (1)', 'BUKAN HOAX', 'BUKAN HOAX (1000)'])
# Sample input
new_s = s.str.replace('\(\d+\)', '').str.strip()
print(new_s)
```

Output:

```
0          HOAX
1          HOAX
2    BUKAN HOAX
3    BUKAN HOAX
dtype: object
```